# Count number of lines that matches between 2 strings from file

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed, grep

I have a challenge. I have this text:

```
characteristic "type"
   value "A"
   value "B"
   value "C" 
   default-value "B" 
exit 
characteristic "active"
   value "no"
   value "yes"
   default-value "no" 
exit
characteristic "traffic"
   value "disabled" 
   value "enabled"
   default-value "enabled"
exit
characteristic "quota" 
   value "enabled"
   default-value "disabled"
exit
characteristic "redirect"
   value "disabled"
   value "enabled"
   default-value "disabled"
exit
```

I want to know how many times is word 'value' between 'characteristic' and 'exit'. So, I hope something like this:

```
3
2
2
1
2
```

I tried to used *sed* and *grep* but I cannot get *sed* give me back *nth* ocurrence of '-n -e "/^characteristic/,/^exit/ p"'. I'm sure *bash* can do it without a lot of *do while/done* and *if*.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say:

```
awk '$1 == "characteristic" { ctr = 0 } $1 == "exit" { print ctr } $1 == "value" { ++ctr }' filename
```

Very simply:

```
$1 == "characteristic" { ctr = 0 }  # Start of a new section: reset counter
$1 == "exit" { print ctr }          # end of section: print counter
$1 == "value" { ++ctr }             # value line: increase counter
```

Comment: **Awesome**. Thanks a lot @Wintermute.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try to solve this with GNU sed's `e` command.

This allows those familiar with sed to inline shell commands to do things like count words.

The idea was to condense each section to one line, and pass it to `grep -ow value | wc -l` to count the occurrences of the word "value."

Command: `sed -f char.sed input-file`

Where the `char.sed` command file for sed is:

```
:a
/exit/{
  s/\n/ /g
  s/-/b/g
  s/^/echo /
  s/$/ | grep -ow value | wc -l/
  e
  n
}
N
ba
```

What that does is `N` on each line until `/exit/` at which point newlines are replaced with spaces, dashes are replaced with b (so that "default-value" doesn't match `grep -w value`).  Then the entire line is prefaced with `echo` and suffixed with `| grep -ow value | wc -l`.  The `e` command is then used to execute the command as constructed and stick the output of the command in the output stream.